# Need help accessing a DropDownList through a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to figure out how to access and store the selection from a dropdownlist to use in a SELECT command in the mainSQL class.

here are the specifics.

The DropDownList (on a page called Page.aspx):

```
    <asp:DropDownList 
    ID="selectInfo1" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="True"
    DataTextField="Info1"
    DataValueField="Info1Key"
    DataSourceID="SqlDB" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

The function where I'm trying to access the DDL (in a seperate class file):

```
public List<ListInfo> getList()
{
List<ListInfo> sList = new List<ListInfo>();
ListInfo objList = null;
    //This is where I need to declare a variable called Info1Key and set it to the value of the ddl!
string queryString = "SELECT [UniqueID], [Date], [Info1], [Info2], [Info3] FROM [ReportedSales] WHERE ([Info1] = ' " + Info1Key + "') ORDER BY [Date]";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        command.Connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                objList = new ListInfo();
                objList.ID = Convert.ToInt16(dataReader["UniqueID"]);
                objList.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dataReader["Date"]);
                objList.Info1 = (dataReader["Info1"] as int?) ?? 0;
                objList.Info2 = (dataReader["Info2"] as int?) ?? 0;
                objList.Info3 = (dataReader["Info3"] as int?) ?? 0;
                sList.Add(objList);
            }
        }
    }
}
return sList;
}
```

This is the only function (im pretty sure) that calls the getList method--

```
    private void FillListActivity()
    {
        List<ListInfo> objList = new List<ListInfo>();
        objList = new mainSQL().getList();

        ReportingGV.DataSource = objList;
        ReportingGV.DataBind();
    }
```

NEW PROBLEM-- GV is no longer changing when I change the DDL.

One way that I could fix that was change the Page_Load in Page.aspx.cs as follows:

Originally:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!isPostBack)
    {
        FillSalesActivity();
    }
}
```

Working, but will I have problems?:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillSalesActivity();
    }
```

Comment: Why not to pass ddl value as parameter of method? Also consider to use SqlParameters

Comment: @lazyberezovsky i would do that, but i have no idea how. I've added the function that calls it (located in Page.aspx.cs) to the original post if you want to see that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want your external classes to know or care anything about UI elements (such as drop down lists).  They should be as UI-agnostic as possible.

Instead, what you want to do in this case is pass the value to the function.  So you'd change the function signature to something like this:

```
public List<ListInfo> getList(string Info1Key)
{
    // The code is the same, just use the Info1Key parameter that's been passed to the function.
}
```

And then you'd call the function like this:

```
private void FillSalesActivity()
{
    List<SalesInfo> objSalesList = new List<SalesInfo>();
    objSalesList = new mainSQL().getSalesList(selectInfo1.SelectedValue);

    SalesReportingGV.DataSource = objSalesList;
    SalesReportingGV.DataBind();
}
```

A few things to note:

- You'll want to include error-checking on your page to make sure there's a value `SelectedValue` before bothering to call the function.
- You should *really* look into SQL injection vulnerabilities, because your code has one.  *Never* implicitly trust a value coming from the client, even if it's from a drop down list and you think you control those.  You don't.  The client can send any value they want if they choose to, and that value can contain SQL code which your function would merrily run against your database with all the permissions it needs.  Look into using "parameterized queries" or, even better, an ORM framework.  Something like Linq To Sql has a pretty quick setup and low learning curve and gets you a lot of functionality.

Comment: This works great, thanks! the only problem is that the GridView that the query is populating doesn't change when you change the dropdownlist selection. do i have to add a button for that functionality that calls FillSalesActivity again or.......?

Comment: @digitalfrenchfry: Any number of bugs might cause that behavior.  For example, a common mistake in WebForms is to re-populate the drop down list in `Page_Load` every time instead of wrapping it in a check for `!IsPostBack`.  (Read up on the page life cycle in Web Forms, `Page_Load` gets executed on post-back before the event handlers do.)

Comment: Previously, my Page_Load was only if (!IsPostBack) { FillSalesActivity(); }, and removing the if-statement obviously fixed the problem.... do you think this solution will cause problems down the line?

Comment: @digitalfrenchfry: Sorry, _removing_ the `if` fixed the problem?  I'm not sure I understand what you're saying now.  Any misunderstanding of the page life cycle can cause problems down the line :)  Maybe update the question with more complete code and indicate what the current issue is?

Comment: Updated the question, new stuff is at the bottom!

Comment: @digitalfrenchfry: Ah, I see what you're saying now.  No, populating the GV shouldn't happen in `Page_Load` in response to selecting a value.  Populating the drop down list with the selectable values should happen in `Page_Load` (within `!IsPostBack`), then populating the GV should happen in the event handler for the selection change for the drop down list.  (If it needs to be populated with a default selection on the initial load then you can do that within `!IsPostBack` in `Page_Load` as well.)